# Implementation contraint: The class feature only_from_type uses an inline agent

Tags: eiffel

Is there a semantic behind not being able to have an agent into a `ensure class` routine or is it a current compiler restriction?

```
only_from_type (some_items: CHAIN[like Current]; a_type: detachable like {ENUMERATE}.measuring_point_type_generation): LINKED_LIST[like Current]
        -- extends Result with given some_items which are equal to given type
    do
        create Result.make
        across
            some_items is l_item
        loop
            check
                attached_type: attached l_item.type as l_type
            then
                if attached a_type as l_a_type and then l_type.is_equal (l_a_type) then
                    Result.extend (l_item)
                end
            end
        end
    ensure
        some_items.for_all (
            agent (an_item: like Current; a_type_2: detachable like {ENUMERATE}.measuring_point_type_generation) do
                if attached a_type_2 as l_type_2_a and then
                    attached an_item.type as l_item_type and then
                    l_item_type.is_equal (l_type_2_a)
                then
                    Result := True
                end
            end (a_type)
            )
        instance_free: Class
    end
```

### gives following error

And I think there is a typo here, shouldn't it be `Implementation constraint` instead of `contraint`?

```
Error code: VUCR

Implementation contraint: The class feature only_from_type uses an inline agent.
What to do: Remove the inline agent from the code or make the feature a non-class one.
Class: MEASURING_POINT
Feature: only_from_type
Line: 183
        some_items.for_all (
->        agent (an_item: like Current; a_type_2: detachable like {ENUMERATE}.measuring_point_type_generation) do
            if attached a_type_2 as l_type_2_a and then
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An inline agent (like a regular feature) takes an implicit argument - current object. In a class feature (where it is used in the example), there is no current object. Therefore, an inline agent cannot be called from a class feature.

On the other hand, it might be possible to check that the agent does not use `Current`, and, therefore, is safe to use in the class feature. The compiler reporting the error does not implement such a functionality, and reports an implementation constraint error instead.